# Put editor templates in view's folder with ASP.NET Core MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

with MVC 4 I was able to put a view's editor templates into the view's folder: `AwesomeApp/Views/UserMgmt/EditorTemplates/UserSettings.cshtml`.

Now I am using ASP.NET Core MVC 6 and it does not find the editor template. I have to put them into `AwesomeApp/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/UserSettings.cshtml`. What needs to be configured so I do not have to put all of my editor templates in this one folder?

I am using the latest version of Telerik's Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC. But I guess it's something in the application itself.

Best regards,
   Carsten

Comment: have you tried to change this to ViewComponent?

Comment: We switched back to MVC 5 for various reasons. So I am not able to check this anymore.

Comment: Using the `IViewLocationExpander` interface should be able to do the trick. An example is available [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/view-location-expander-aspnet5-mvc6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works out of the box in (at least) core 2.2. In [one of the demos](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Mvc/test/WebSites/HtmlGenerationWebSite/Views/HtmlGeneration_Home/EditorTemplates) they have put the EditorTemplates folder underneath a views folder, not the shared folder.

I tested this myself using the following code...

```
public class TestEditorForModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Testing a string property")]
    public string StringProp { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Testing an integer property")]
    [Range(100, 1000)]
    public int IntProp { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Testing a decimal property")]
    public decimal DecProp { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new TestEditorForModel
    {
        StringProp = "testing editorfor",
        IntProp = 123,
        DecProp = 123.456m
    });
}
```

Home/EditorTemplates/TestEditorForModel.cshtml

```
@model TestEditorForModel

<div>
    <label asp-for="StringProp"></label>
    <input asp-for="StringProp" placeholder="Testing" />
</div>

<div>
    <label asp-for="IntProp"></label>
    <input asp-for="IntProp" placeholder="123" />
</div>

<div>
    <label asp-for="DecProp"></label>
    <input asp-for="DecProp" placeholder="100.00" />
</div>
```

Home/Index.cshtml

```
@model TestEditorForModel

@Html.EditorFor(m => m)
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Good to know! I cannot test it anymore, but I trust that your screenshot is real. ;)